# 12.10 Firefox 19 is memory hog

Tags: 12.10, firefox

Today I upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 and memory usage of Firefox increased from around 150 MB in 12.04 to 350 MB in 12.10.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiefox has a small memory leakage problem

**To fix it [Try This]**

1. Open Firefox and go to the Address Bar. Type in `about:config` and then press Enter.
2. Right Click in the page and select New -> Boolean.
3. In the box that pops up enter `config.trim_on_minimize`. Press Enter.
4. Now select True and then press Enter.
5. Restart Firefox.

Hope this will help