# Ubuntu 12.04 gets stuck sometimes

Tags: configuration

Sometimes my laptop get stuck while working with firefox as well as some other applications.

My laptop is A Lenovo g560 with:

- CPU: Intel i5 4core
- A  1.5GB graphic card
- 8 GB RAM

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit

Comment: What happens when the laptop 'gets stuck' ? No action at all? Thrashing drives? It it possible to log in remotely? (e.g. has only the X client crashed), ...

Answer (score 0):

You should have to monitor your memory usage and i am sure you are using 12.04 32 bit os so that you are only using 3.6 somthing out of your 8 GB.

**Solutions**

1. Install 64 bit 12.04 Ubuntu
2. If Firefox is latest 19 version than firefox has memory leakage problem and can be fixed by folowing steps on other post 
   [12.10 Firefox 19 is memory hog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272819/12-10-firefox-19-is-memory-hog/272821?noredirect=1#comment342472_272821)
3. Monitor your memory usage and as i am using 12.04 on core i3 4 GB ram i never GOT stuck while using firfox or other programs

See in your system monitor that if you are really using 8 GB of RAM

Comment: If his PC only supports 32-bit, then how can he install 64-bit? He might get more errors then he had before.

Comment: noway your PC is 64-bit as you have core i 5 and 8 GB RAM i am sure you have 64-bit architecture and the pc's that were manufactured before 2010 were only 32-bit but now a days you have 64-bit and as you said you have core i 5 that this is cent percent 64-bit

Comment: This is taken from wikipedia: The first Core i5 using the Nehalem microarchitecture was introduced on **September 8, 2009**. So, this is old.

Comment: hmm than you are not using your 8 gb ram and the simple solution is you have to see that how much memory your system is detecting ? goto menu and search system monitor and system information and tell me how much memory is detected there

Comment: devloper@zamp:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7972412    2628992    5343420          0     237916    1396744
-/+ buffers/cache:     994332    6978080
Swap:      8180732          0    8180732

Comment: above are my mem details. and i am using 64 bit os